# Creating a quotation contract

Tags: scriptwriting, first-time-author, contracts

I am an aspiring script writer who is looking to get his first gig.
An overseas firm approached me to write a script for four one minute commercials.
I have stated my asking price to them but they wanted me to make a quotation that will also include the revision terms. Where would be a good place to start this? Is there any specific or advisable format that I need to follow in order to write the quotation?

Comment: Hi there - this might be a better fit for Freelancing SE (https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) if you want to try and fish over there :)